# Object has no attribute error when python file is called from another python file

Tags: python

I have two python files `Cron.py` and `Workflow.py`. Workflow.py process files which are newly created and `Cron.py` calls `Workflow.py` every 5 seconds using scheduler.

When I execute `Cron.py`, the code works fine until all files to be processed. But as soon as there are `no files` to process, `Cron.py` throws attribute error:

```
ERROR:root:'Cron' object has no attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Workflow.py", line 371, in Start
    self.setupLoggingToFile()
AttributeError: 'Cron' object has no attribute 'setupLoggingToFile'
```

Below is my Cron code:

```
import schedule
from Workflow import Workflow as w
import time
class Cron:

    def start_job(self):
        print('************Cron Job Cycle Started**************')
        w.Start(self)
        print('************Cron Job Cycle Ended **************')

    def Start(self):

        scheduler = schedule()
        scheduler.every(5).seconds.do(self.start_job())
        while 1:
            scheduler.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

A = Cron()
A.start_job()
```

and Workflow.py code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import pyodbc
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from lxml import etree
import os.path
import datetime
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import logging
import logging.handlers
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import json
import pandas
class Workflow:

    def setupLoggingToFile(self):
        logging.basicConfig(
                            # filemode='a',
                            format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                            datefmt= '%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S',
                            level=logging.DEBUG,
                            handlers=[RotatingFileHandler('C:/ExceptionLogFiles/MyLogs', maxBytes = 10485760, backupCount=100)]
                            )


    def Start(self):

        try:
            print('Cron started..')
            # self.createFolders()
            self.setupLoggingToFile()

            print('Files Folder Setup completed ..')

            #Get number of files which are not processed.
            files = self.GetRequestedFilesCount()


            if files[0] > 0:
                print(str(files[0]) + " files to be processed..")

                # Get filing ids and status of files which are to be processed
                resultset = self.GetRequestedFileInfo()

                filingId = []

                for fileid, status in resultset:
                    filingId.append(str(fileid) + "##" + str(status))


                #Create Threads based on number of filings ids to be processed.
                pool = ThreadPool(len(filingId))
                results = pool.map(self.ProcessFile,filingId) ## Process the filingIds in parallel.
                pool.close()
                pool.join()
            else:
                print("No Files to be Processed.")

        except AttributeError:
            logging.exception("'Cron' object has no attribute ", exc_info=True)
        except Exception:
            logging.exception("ProcessFile Function: Filing ID: {} ".format(filingId), exc_info=True)



A = Workflow()
A.Start()
```

Any idea how to tell `Cron.py` to stop peacefully without exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in `Cron.start_job`, with the line

```
w.Start(self)
```

The `self` variable inside `Cron` is the Cron instance.
You then pass it to the Start() method of the Workflow **class** w.

This workflow class then calls `self.setupLoggingToFile()`, but `self` is now the Cron instance you passed, and not the Workflow instance that it should be.
Therefore, the error message says exactly what you expect: `'Cron' object has no attribute 'setupLoggingToFile'`

A possible solution is to create an instance of your `Workflow` class and pass it to the `start_job` method of Cron, for example:

```
from Workflow import Workflow


class Cron:

    def start_job(self, workflow_instance):
        workflow_instance.Start()

    def Start(self, workflow_instance):
        scheduler = schedule()
        scheduler.every(5).seconds.do(self.start_job(workflow_instance))
        # ...

    # NOTE: large parts of original code left out for clarity


w = Workflow()
c = Cron()
c.start_job(w)
```

The question remains whether the code, with these changes, does what you expect it to do. Depending on what exactly the Workflow class does, you may get some problems if a job does not finish within 5 seconds.

Comment: Changing `setupLoggingToFile` to a classmethod won't help, because calling `w.Start()` will still fail. The code in `Cron` needs an instance of `WorkFlow`. But it's not clear to me whether the OP wants to create a new instance for each job, or import `A` from the other module and re-use it.

Comment: Agreed, so another class method. Or the real solution: refactoring.

Comment: No - classmethods will not work at all, and aren't necessary. What you need to do is create (or import) *an instance of WorkFlow*. Using the class object itself is just plain wrong.

Comment: Why wouldn't classmethods work? I agree it is ugly to use them in the case presented above, but it should work. And I thought it would be instructive to show the answer this way (although I would not like to see it in actual code, hence my suggestion to refactor).

Comment: Changing `Start` to a classmethod will break all the other instance methods that are called inside the method. Read the OP's code!

Comment: OK, agreed. I somehow assumed that OP did not want to instantiate w for some reason because he tried to pass `self`. But it looks like you are right and that was not his intention at all.